# Is UK income which is exempted in UK taxable in India

Tags: taxes, india, non-resident, income

I am a Indian citizen working in UK on a work permit. My salary in Uk is 36000 pounds.I have heard that in UK salary of 10500 pounds is exempted from tax and my company is paying tax on the remaining salary. So will I have to pay tax on the amount of 10500 pounds in India which is exempted in UK?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for the given financial year, 1 April to 31 March you have stayed more than 182 days out of India, you will be classified as non-resident Indian, NRI for tax purposes.

If you are NRI, you don't have to pay any tax in India.

If you are not NRI you have to pay taxes on the full salary 36,000 GBP in India as per tax rates.